# Push/Fold situation

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, short-stack, final-table, fold-equity

I'm following *Kill Everyone* tables for *push/fold* situations but i have some difficulties where there's limping action before me from the `big stacks`.

Say, i'm in FT and the large stack with about `13.5 BB` and an `M of 6` just calls from **UTG** with stats of `28/3` over 39 hands (stats are per blind level i think in PT4). I put him on some hand like `Kx,Qx` any face but nothing terrible, any hand that has potential post-flop and can use his stack to take down the pot later in the hand.

I have an `M of 2` and my hand is 3♠3⋄ and am `3rd` to act (MP early).
Now *Kill Everyone* recommends to shove from my position if there's no action before me. My question is:

> *Do you think i should tighten my push/fold requirements if there's a limp before or even fold and forget about shove since there's action anyhow, even a limp?*

I mean, sure there's action earlier, although is just a loose limp by the big stack and not a raise? Does the limps earlier can mess a clear push situation? Do i have to wait for clear *first-in vigorish* for push/fold?

The actual hand ended the tourney for me since villain was holding 8♠8♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should consider limps as action because if you have only M of 2 and he already put 1 BB he gets good pot odds and he is very likely to call.

That said with such a low stack you have to take action and if you do not have any reason to believe a lot more people will call you should still go in. If he limps 1/4 of his hands you will get your flip most of the time.

Comment: very reasonable, i frequently forget to compare their contribution to the pot, as i think more the chance i'm gonna get called by others. My conclusion is that the lower my stack and M and early position, the less thought i should give to stats and sophisticated play and instead play directly the tables as if there wasn't any action. Thanx!